# Rails 2.3: Replace record associations instead of delete

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So here is the general issue:

I have 3 tables, for simplicity we'll call them a,b,c

table a
id

table b
id
a_id
c_id

table c
id

So a record in b, associates a record from a and c.

And the problem:
When a user submits the form some number of hashes are submitted, each representing a record in b that needs to be filled.  Right now I'm simply deleting and re-adding, I would like to be able to iterate over the existing associations and (and here's where it gets tricky) if there are more associations in the database (D) than submitted (S) then delete D-S entries, if D-S is equal then just replace the current entries, and if D-S is negative, add S-D records.

Then update them all to the new associations.

I tried doing this with a loop however the problem is the active record query returns an array and I still have a hash to iterate over.  Since I can't have two arrays looping in sync with each other, I'm not sure where to go from here.  Any ideas?

Note: I can post actual code however the controller function handling this is very long.

---

EDIT: I feel like I wasn't specific enough here although I'm becoming more sure this will all have to be manual here is a rough example of what I'm looking for.

```
submitted_hash[:whatever].each do |key,value|
    #value.first_submit
    #value.second_submit
end

ModelName.find(:all, :conditions => ["fk_ref = ?", params[:fk_ref]]).each do |model_value|
end
```

Now if the "ModelName.find" returns more than is currently in "submitted_hash", then we need to create more references to fill the need.

If "ModelName.find" returns less than "submitted_hash", then we will be adding the difference, as rows, in the database.

If they are equal, not action - on this part - is required.

Finally I then need to use the ModelName.find(:all, :conditions) which should now return the  same amount as is in our hash (I have gotten this far).

Now somehow I need to loop through our ModelName.find and the params[:subbmited_hash] at the same time so that record 1 gets replaced by submission 1, then record 2 with submit 2, etc.

Note: So I can get my intention across, what I'm attempting to do is replace the records without any deletes that aren't necessary, if someone submits 6 and needs 3, my code right now will delete the 6, and add the 3 new ones.  This works but it permanently removes 6 rows (in this case) every time its updated.  I would like it to delete 3 (the difference of the two values) and update the remaining 3 to the newly submitted values.

Answer (score 1):

Your text wasn't very clear for me, but the closest thing that you can be looking for is the mysql **replace** command.

It inserts a new row if there isn't a correpondent one, otherwise it does an update.

Like this:

```
  REPLACE INTO b (id, a_id, c_id) VALUES (5, 2, 3);
```

ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

But it does not remove old invalid entries. I think you will need to do it for yourself/manually. Databases don't work this way.

It's possible to do it with ORM frameworks. I don't know anything about rails, but maybe this page can help you:

http://blog.gridworlds.com/rails/delete-or-delete-removing-things-in-rails

Or try looking for rails "delete orphan"